Bijective functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$
Consider a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Is it correct to say that a function of this type can never be bijective?
I have attempted to prove this by contradiction in the following way, but I'm not sure:
Consider the generic level set $I_z = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: f(x,y) = z, z \in \mathbb{R} \}$. If $f$ is supposed bijective, then for each $z \in \mathbb{R}$ the cardinality $|I_z|$ = 1. The auxiliary function $g_z(x,y):= f(x,y) - z$ has only one zero, so its sign never changes. Whatever $g_z$'s sign is, the point $(x_z,y_z)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g_z(x_z,y_z) = 0$ has to be a maximum or a minimum of $g_z$, so $(x_z,y_z)$ has to be a critical point of $g_z$ and $f$. But repeating this for each $z\in \mathbb{R}$ makes the function $f$ constant, so $f$ is not bijective.
I've also found out that usually the implicit function theorem can be used to prove such statements, but I do not know how to use it in this case.

See invariance of domain.

@anomaly i think op just wants a smooth map not a diffeomorphism

@AjinShajiJose: Right, but a continuous bijection $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ would give a continuous injection $if:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R^2}$ for some convenient embedding $i:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, forcing $if(\mathbb{R}^2) = i(\mathbb{R})$ to be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That works without assuming $f^{-1}$ is smooth, or even continuous.

What do you think about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcMZsF4vDbo ?

@Piquito That is a nice example. But I'm not sure that it is differentiable

@anomaly ok. but how do u use Invariance of Domain?

@AjinShajiJose: It forces $i(\mathbb{R})$ to be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which it is not.

@anomaly i get what ur saying but how is $i(\mathbb{R})$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

@AjinShajiJose: Invariance of domain guarantees that $if(\mathbb{R}^2) = i(\mathbb{R})$ is open, being the image of the open set $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the embedding $if:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

@anomaly oh yes, i was a bit confused. thanks for your time

@AjinShajiJose: No worries, hope that helped.

@Tom Avery.- I believe (without be entirely sur) that it is not possible with even continuous.

This results hold in just the continuous category, but you can also use the constant rank theorem here (and note that the rank is either $0$ or $1$ at each point).

A continuous image of a connected set is connected, Proof of "the continuous image of a connected set is connected"
If your function is bijective and you remove one point from $R^2$ then the image is not connected. So the answer is no.

Could you clarify? I do not understand how can this theorem be used to answer my question

If the function is differentiable it is continuous, $R^2\setminus{p}$ is connected and  since $f$ is bijective $R\setminus{f(p)}$ is not connected. Contradicting that the image of a connected set is a connected set.
